# SNS Topic is not sending the pipeline event change emails when configured through Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating a `cloudwatch event` which will trigger when there is state change in my `code pipeline` and assigned to a `SNS topic`. I am doing all the above configuration through `Cloudformation Stack`. Below is my stack template

```
{
    "Description": "Triggering CodePipeline notifications.",
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "EmailAddress": {
            "Description": "Email Address",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "EventRule": {
            "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "EventRule",
                "EventPattern": {
                    "source": [
                        "aws.codepipeline"
                    ],
                    "detail-type": [
                        "CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change"
                    ],
                    "detail": {
                        "state": [
                            "FAILED"
                        ],
                        "pipeline": [
                           "mypipelinename"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "State": "ENABLED",
                "Targets": [
                    {
                        "Arn": {
                            "Ref": "MySNSTopic"
                        },
                        "Id": "PipelineNotificationTopic",
                        "InputTransformer": {
                            "InputTemplate": "\"The Pipeline <pipeline> has failed.\" ",
                            "InputPathsMap": {
                                "pipeline": "$.detail.pipeline"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "MySNSTopic": {
            "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
            "Properties": {
             "TopicName": "Huaaa",
                "Subscription": [
                    {
                        "Endpoint": {
                            "Ref": "EmailAddress"
                        },
                        "Protocol": "email"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is creating all the necessary resources like cloudwatch event and SNS subscription and sending a notification for my email address for confirmation. But when there is a `state change` in mypipeline this is not triggering any email notification.

But when i created a new `SNSTopic` and created a `subscription` using `aws console` and attached it to the cloudwatch event that was created by `cloudformation stack` as a target it worked fine. I can able to receive notifications when there is a change.

Am i missing anything in my Template?

Thanks
Any help is apprecicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to set the `AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy` which allows to publish.

For example (written in .yml)

```
MySNSTopicPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    Topics:
      - !Ref MySNSTopic
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: '*'
          Action: sns:Publish
          Resource: !Ref MySNSTopic
```

Comment: Thanks @MaikaY. I have few questions: Should i have to use only `AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy` cant i use `IAM:Role` and give SNS permissions to it ? And also in your code snippet can i keep the `Prinicpal` as my `Cloudwatchevent ARN` ? Because when i tried keeping it in `Principal` of `MySNSTopicPolicy` i received an error status 400.

Comment: @Private If you want to restrict the `sns:publish` action only to your CloudWatch event you could easily exchange the `*` with the `ARN` of your `EventRule` resource. Please keep in mind that its possible to add **only one** `TopicPolicy` per `Topic`.